# Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin, ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My flutter project doesn't build and throws the following error:

> Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.Find
> the latest version on
> https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions and then
> update the same in android/build.gradle

as `ext.kotlin_version=<latest-version>`

I have updated build.gradle in android/build.gradle to the following as suggested :

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
```

However the error continues to persist. Upon inspecting gradle versions by running

> ./gradlew --version

I get the following result :

```html
Gradle 7.4.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          18.0.2.1 (Oracle Corporation 18.0.2.1+1-1)
OS:           Windows 11 10.0 amd64
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Kotlin Gradle plugin is not the same as Kotlin version.

Comment: @TheLibrarian, how do i solve the error. Besides, i have just updated the information to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Find `build.gradle` file that uses `kotlin-gradle-plugin` and increase the version :-)

Comment: There is nothing mentioned as kotlin-gradle-plugin. Couldn't find it.

Comment: Then you might need to add it.

Comment: Can you tell me how ?

Comment: Hi. I have another question. Can you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74284254/flutternosuchmethoderrorthe-method-of-was-called-on-null?noredirect=1#comment131147155_74284254

Answer (score 0):

you should check gradle version

use same version 1.5.31

```
classpath  'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31'
```

Comment: The above code line statement isn't there. Do i need to add it ?

Comment: Hi. I have another question. Can you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74284254/flutternosuchmethoderrorthe-method-of-was-called-on-null?noredirect=1#comment131147155_74284254